# Parsing JSon Data FlightAware

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I am using the flight aware service to get flight information but I am having trouble getting the data in a way I can use.

**Json response is:**

```
{
    "AirlineInfoResult": {
        "name": "US Airways",
        "shortname": "US Airways",
        "callsign": "Cactus",
        "location": "Tempe, AZ",
        "country": "United States",
        "url": "http://www.usairways.com/",
        "phone": "+1-800-428-4322"
    }
}
```

And this is the code I am using but nothing is returned

```
NSMutableDictionary * routeRes;
routeRes = [json objectForKey: @"AirlineInfoResult"];
NSMutableArray * res;
res = [json objectForKey: @"url"];
for (NSMutableDictionary * flight in res) {
    NSLog(@"actual arrival time= %@", [flight objectForKey: @"url"]);
}
```

What am I missing in getting this data?

Comment: `res` should a `NSString`.

Comment: please give URl of the response

Comment: The url response is the top part

Comment: If I change res to NSString I get this error NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff72f4af10

Comment: In your answer you don't have "actual arrival time". and `res = [routeRes objectForKey:@"url"];`

Comment: well, first of all slog your route Res, then res, and i have a question for you - why are you searching for dictionaries in your array(res)? you've already getting your url in res

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change below line:

res = [json objectForKey:@"url"];

with

res = [routeRes objectForKey:@"url"];

Comment: that produces this error  countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10050c970
2014-03-29 10:16:54.423 FlightAwareCommandtool[471:303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10050c970'